# How to pass a context (this) in a Tracker.autorun function?

Tags: meteor, typescript, reactive-programming

This class will display this = `undefined`. How to pass the context in?

```
class MeteorAccount implements IService{

  constructor() {
    Tracker.autorun(function () {
      //observe
      Meteor.userId());
      console.log(this);//undefined
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

The [Function.bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
class MeteorAccount implements IService{
    constructor() {
        Tracker.autorun(function() {
            //observe
            Meteor.userId());
            console.log(this);//undefined
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Or the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
class MeteorAccount implements IService{
    constructor() {
        Tracker.autorun(() => {
            //observe
            Meteor.userId());
            console.log(this);//undefined
        });
    }
}
```

---

#### Edit

There's another option, I just don't like it, but it's how people used to do it before the arrow function (not sure why not the bind option):

```
class MeteorAccount implements IService{
    constructor() {
        var self = this;
        
        Tracker.autorun(function() {
            //observe
            Meteor.userId());
            console.log(self);//undefined
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: + infinite points to gave me a real reason to use arrow functions! Thanks a lot Nitzan, you make my day!

Comment: @DanielN arrow functions are a lot of fun and very useful once you get used to them, though in a lot of cases I still like to use the `bind` function as you can also bind function parameters to it other than the context.